# Scrutinizing content while reviewing edits

Tags: discussion, review

Sometimes while I am running through the "Suggested Edits" review queue, I often find myself scrutinizing the quality of the content along with the actual edits that were suggested. Sometimes I find posts that are just awful and I open them up in a new tab, check for myself and then take appropriate action if needed. Then I will go back to looking through the suggested edit and take whatever appropriate action is needed there also.

Is this an OK practice? Does it hold up some sort of review process that is unbeknownst to me? Or does the show go on despite my being sidetracked of the content in the post?

Comment: You mean you also downvote or vote to close in addition to improving/rejecting the suggested edit?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean. It's usually "Approving" or "Rejecting". Rarely improving. Should I just "Skip" the edit review in such a case?

Comment: Good question, will think of proper answer based on my own experience. Anyway review audit is not relevant, removing the tag. Also, you are discussing the review process itself, not the suggested edits.

Comment: My dear no! Keep doing that! If the edit is not helpful, not good or fails for any other reason, reject it. If you happen to downvote the post, close to vote or any similar thing on the way, that's an added bonus.

Comment: I do the same but when reviewing posts (first, low quality, etc.), stepping out of the queue may cause one to make a wrong decision. I happened to ask a question about that a bit earlier: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182929/168269. So you must make a decision based on what you see in the review page.

Comment: @M. Night DemonBobby: Noted, I just don't want to mess up some process. It seems like Sha Wiz Dow Ard has a good tip in his answer though.

Comment: @Gert suggested edits review is different as you can only act upon the edit suggestion itself from within the review process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: yes, this is totally OK and just improves the overall quality of the site.

One thing I would like to mention is that it's better to do the other things (vote, close or even answer) to the post **after** reviewing the suggested edit and not before as usually those items are reviewed really fast you would lose your vote.

So first, open the post in separate tab. Decide if the edit itself is good or bad and act upon it then go to the other tab and take your time downvoting, upvoting or posting new answer.

Comment: The last paragraph is some solid advice. I'll definitely start doing that.

Answer (score 6):

> Sometimes I find posts that are just awful and I open them up in a new tab, check for myself and then take appropriate action if needed.

This is great, you should definitely continue to do this.

The suggested edits queue is *independent* of these other actions (e.g. closing questions or flagging), and you should continue to handle the suggested edit separately.